# xpages how to copy a page content to a custom control

Tags: xpages

We have a Notes Client application which has a page with a lot of text. ( static text )

I tried just to copy and paste its content into a custom control ( this custom control lays on an XPage ), but the font of the text is changed to a default font. Also the paragraphs and the allignment aren't kept.

How can I easily copy the content from the Notes Client page to a custom control/XPage?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest is to preview the Page in a browser and copy and paste the content from there. That will have all the relevant formatting. But bear in mind that traditional Domino web also adds a lot of unnecessary HTML, so you'll probably want to clean up the HTML before pasting it into the XPage.

Comment: thanks for your answer. By 'copy and paste the content from there' - you mean just copy the content from the Page previewed in a broswer? I tried and it's exactly the same as if I'm copying it from a Notes Client.

Comment: Copy the HTML source from the browser

Comment: If going the "copy HTML" route (which is probably best), you can save some hassle by turning on Enhanced HTML Generation in the DB properties and add a field called "$$HTMLOptions" to the form with a value of "XMLCompatibleHTML=1". That should close the generated HTML tags in an XML-friendly way. Alternatively, run it through a text editor with Tidy.

Comment: @MFG Flay Are you happy with the look of previewed document in browser? Make it look good on the web, then copy that HTML to custom control.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth also with the <head> and <body> tags, inside the <xp:view> ?

Comment: That's it - if it doesn't look good, you have to retype it in some HTML editor, as Jesse suggests (Tidy).